# Meteor Iron Router Login Route Pass-thru for Facebook accounts not working

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-accounts

**The Issue:**

When my regular users using the standard email/password 'accounts-password' go to a login redirected page , they can enter the credentials and the router will proceed to render the requested page.

**For example:**
/private_page (requires login). The user attempts to go to http://foo.com/private_page they are presented with the Login page. The user enters username/password correctly and now the /private_page displays.

This works, what does NOT work...

Same example as above, but now the user is authenticating with Facebook 'accounts-facebook'. Everything is the same as before and the user has succesful login with Facebook and is able to get into my web application except the route never displays the /private_page. It stays on the authenticated /login page without showing the login template.

**IN A NUTSHELL**
How do I make the facebook authenticated users pass-thru and route to the requested route like the regular password based users operate ?

Iron Router Config:

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function () {    
    if  (!Meteor.userId() && !Meteor.loggingIn()) {
        this.redirect('login');
        this.stop();
    } else {
        this.next();
    }
},{except: ['login', 'contact, 'terms']});
```

Meteor packages:

```
accounts-password@1.3.6
accounts-facebook@1.2.0
service-configuration@1.0.11
useraccounts:bootstrap
useraccounts:iron-routing
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally came to a solution.

After reviewing the Github issues for the Meteor package: (meteor-useraccounts)I found the exact issue I have been having.

https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/issues/685

I spent too much time trying to make the hooks fire correctly for my usage of oAuth Facebook with Meteor. My final solution was too just connect directly into the Meteor method calls and create my own login, registration, password reset, etc forms.

The up-side is that I now have full control of the forms and I don't need to deal with extra package.

If anyone comes finds this posting and is having issues making 'meteor-useraccounts' fire hooks like the postSignUpHook , you may decide to just scrap the package and make your own user account templates and connect the logic to use the native Meteor methods.

This particular question I submitted was because the oAuth Facebook would login but I was unable to make it redirect to the originally requested route. The oAuth works and my user can login to my web app, but I cannot get them to the originally requested url.

How did I solve this:

*lib/routes*

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function () {    
    if  (!Meteor.userId() && !Meteor.loggingIn()) {
        originalUrl = this.originalUrl;
        this.redirect('login');
        this.stop();
    } else {
        this.next();
    }
},{except: ['login', 'resetPwd', 'help'] });
```

The key point to take away from the snippet above is the global variable I declare **originalUrl**. This is using the routers **this.originalUrl**. This url contains the original url that the user entered and is captured the moment before the iron-router redirects to the login page.

Now on the login page I created my two different login methods using my own custom template. They both are using the **Meteor.loginWithPassword** and **Meteor.loginWithFacebook** methods.

*client/login.js*

```
    'click #fb-login' : function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        Meteor.loginWithFacebook({}, function(err){
            if(err) {
              // some error occured
            }
            else {
                if(Router.current().route._path == "/login" && typeof originalUrl == "undefined")
                    Router.go('/');
                else
                    Router.go(originalUrl);
            }
        });
    }
```

Hope this helps anyone else who might come across this issue.